# How to plot a second graph instead of color coding in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, colors

i just started with my master thesis and i already am in trouble with my capability/understanding of matlab.

The thing is, i have a trajectory on a surface of a planet/moon whatever (a .mat with the time, and the coordinates. Then i have some .mat with time and the measurement at that time.

I am able to plot this as a color coded trajectory (using the measurement and the coordinates) in scatter(). This works awesomely nice.

However my problem is that i need something more sophisticated.
I now need to take the trajectory and instead of color-coding it, i am supposed to add the graph (value) of the measurement (which is given for each point) to the trajectory (which is not always a straight line). I will added a little sketch to explain what i want. The red arrow shows what i want to add to my plot and the green shows what i have.

[image]

Comment: Try 'hold on' before you start with drawing your figure. If you now plot something else it will be plotted inside your graph.

Comment: thanks, but that is not the poblem at all.. the thing is that i want to plot points on a specific distance from the line (and points) in an right angle.

Comment: maybe it would also be nice to add an y-axis on the black-lined plot (which is as well "rotated")

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but you may want to look into `doc rotate` Furthermore it does not answer the question, but it would be easier to color the line depending on its value, rather than positioning the line over some diagonal line.

Comment: Then I don't get your problem, you basically take your line as x axis and transform the graph (red arrow) by adding the coordinates of your line (green arrow). If green is not a line interpolate these points and consider this as your x axis (which is not linear but somewhat polynomial). If it is not linear but you want to consider it as a line do linear regression.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you of course would need the surface normal of your line or interpolation in order to draw it correctly but I consider this more relevant for math.stackexchange than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always transform your data yourself: (using the same notation as @Shai)

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = x;
m = 10*sin(x);
```

So what you need is the vector normal to the curve at each datapoint:

```
dx = diff(x); % backward finite differences for 2:end points
dx = [dx(1) dx]; % forward finite difference for 1th point
dy = diff(y);
dy = [dy(1) dy];
curve_tang = [dx ; dy];
% rotate tangential vectors 90° counterclockwise
curve_norm = [-dy; dx];
% normalize the vectors:
nrm_cn = sqrt(sum(abs(curve_norm).^2,1));
curve_norm = curve_norm ./ repmat(sqrt(sum(abs(curve_norm).^2,1)),2,1);
```

Multiply that vector with the measurement (`m`), offset it with the datapoint coordinates and you're done:

```
mx = x + curve_norm(1,:).*m;
my = y + curve_norm(2,:).*m;
```

plot it with:

```
figure; hold on
axis equal;
scatter(x,y,[],m);
plot(mx,my)
```

[image: straightline_sine]

which is imo exactly what you want. This example has just a straight line as coordinates, but this code can handle any curve just fine:

```
x=0:0.1:10;y=x.^2;m=sin(x);
```

[image: parabole_sine]

```
t=0:pi/50:2*pi;x=5*cos(t);y=5*sin(t);m=sin(5*t);
```

[image: circle_sine]

Comment: Thank you very much. That does look like an excellent solution to my problem. I will try it out as soon as i have access to my data again.

Comment: +1: Indeed, if the angle is unknown, you'll be needing the gradient of the trajectory.

Comment: Hi Gunther.
Somehow i still have trouble in doing this.
An error shows up that the matrices are not the same dimension.
I only input one (63--- x 1) thus that should be ok or not?

'Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in DensGeo (line 99)
dx = [dx(1) dx]; % forward finite difference for 1th point'

Also if i skip this part, the next inconsistency shows up at the normallization part:

'Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in DensGeo (line 109)
curve_norm = curve_norm ./ repmat(sqrt(sum(abs(curve_norm).^2,1)),2,1);'

Comment: my code was intended for row vectors, the one you're using is a column vector. For a quick fix: [transpose](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) your input

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is to rotate your actual data around an origin point at a certain angle. This is pretty simple, as you only need to multiply the coordinates by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_algebra). You can then use `hold on` and `plot` to overlay your plot with the rotated points, as suggested in the comments.

#### Example

First, let's generate some data that resembles yours and create a scatter plot:

```
% # Generate some data
t = -20:0.1:20;
idx = (t ~= 0);
y = ones(size(t));
y(idx) = abs(sin(t(idx)) ./ t(idx)) .^ 0.25;

% # Create a scatter plot
x = 1:numel(y);
figure
scatter(x, x, 10, y, 'filled')
```

Now let's rotate the points (specified by the values of `x` and `y`) around (0, 0) at a 45° angle:

```
P = [x(:) * sqrt(2), y(:) * 100] * [1, 1; -1, 1] / sqrt(2);
```

and then plot them on top of the scatter plot:

```
hold on
axis square
plot(P(:, 1), P(:, 2))
```

Note the additional things have been done here for visualization purposes:

1. The final x-coordinates have been stretched (by `sqrt(2)`) to the appropriate length.
2. The final y-coordinates have been magnified (by 100) so that the rotated plot stands out.
3. The axes have been squared to avoid distortion.

This is what you should get:

[image]

Comment: This was also my first thought, but the trajectory might not be a straight line. I think you can even see this in OP's example figure, hence the need for the curve gradient

Comment: Thank you as well. Yes Gunter Struyf is right and my trajectory does  not always go through the origin (i need to analyze more than 10 data-sets). Also, I plot polar coordinates (which are converted to cartesian coordinate system) so the origin is in the middle of the picture. I also might not know the angle it makes directly. But this is still a nice solution for those cases (through origin and straight lines).

Comment: @IceQueeny In case that you don't know the angle you'll indeed be needing the gradient, just like Gunther suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are interested in 3D plotting. 
If I understand your question correctly, you have a 2D curve represented as `[x(t), y(t)]`. 
Additionally, you have some value `m(t)` for each point. 
Thus we are looking at the plot of a 3D curve `[x(t) y(t) m(t)]`.
you can easily achieve this using

```
plot3( x, y, m ); % assuming x,y, and m are sorted w.r.t t
```

alternatively, you can use the 3D version of scatter

```
scatter3( x, y, m );
```

pick your choice.

Nice plot BTW.

Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But my plan was to keep my 3D data in 2D, so that i can compare the values of the measurement to the geographical characteristics on the ground of my planet/moon (like geysers or cracks). I am able to put the background image in, thats no problem..