# Plot a function in function of a function

Tags: matlab, plot

I don't know if I'll be able to fully explain what I need. But I'll try.

I've got curved frame and on this frame, I have to draw a graph of forces/moments/stress. The frame has 9 intervals. For now I stretched the frame and draw the diagrams on the stretched -zero- line.

But what should I do if I want to draw it on the real frame?

**A few examples:**

- I try to do something like this:
  [image]
- This is the real frame:
  [image]

With corresponding forces affecting the frame.

If I stretch the final forces/moment/stress diagrams, it looks like this: [image]

And I need it like this: 
[image]

I hope you know what I mean :-) I'm not a Photoshop guy :-)

Edit: In my opinion, if you draw any plot, you draw it in function of the *zero line*, but what if you change the zero line to different function.

It's like plotting 2 lines ans fill the area between them, but only the bottom line is function of a normal *zero line*, and the second line is a function the first line.

- I think we could go from a point where:
  [image]
  So that the second function will draw correspondigly to the first function function. :-)

Any thoughts welcome :-)

Comment: we'll try to answer the desired answer with a correct answer, but if the answer does not answer your "answer seeking" don't re-answer to our answer angrily ;)

Comment: +1 for the crazy talk and hand drawings ;)

Comment: very interesting question BTW. I am completely not able to do that, but it would be great to know how

Comment: First thoughts: convert your plot to an image and use `imtransform`. That is, if you have the image processing toolbox...

Comment: OK so usually, in these kinds of plots, the y-direction is everywhere perpendicular to the x-axis. Your photoshopped thingy shows the y-axis always vertical.  Which one would you prefer?

Comment: this might help you, but I intended it for line plots on another curve, not bars. still might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053766/how-to-plot-a-second-graph-instead-of-color-coding-in-matlab/14055418#14055418

Comment: Oh, that was fast! Thank all of you :-) @RodyOldenhius: will look in that for sure. Interesting approach ;-) (About the Photoshop thingie, that's why I said I'm not a photoshop master. y-axis needs to be perpendicular to the function bellow.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: wow, really nice, I'll look into that too, that can be it :-)

Comment: How did you create these forces/moment/stress diagrams? Are they shaded line plots or bar plots? Would be nice if you could post that code and some sample data (maybe also for the frame).

Comment: Oki, these are the equations for N, T, M (first three diagrams) || http://imgur.com/sBoQo3E || I then "recompute" them by *ones(length) so I have every one of them the same length. And this is how I plot them in figures: || http://imgur.com/zfGlrMy ||. (That's the first diagram for Forces). N1r "is" N1, `xip` is `[x1p;x2p;x3p...x9p]` which corresponds to _length_ of an interval.
//// I don't have equations for the frame. Only x-y coordinations of points.

Answer (score 2):

General idea for such plot is following:

Let curve from your top plot described as y = f(x). In matlab your receive set of points:

```
x = x0:dx:xf;
y = f(x);
```

f should be external function or formula.

Than you have zero-line function y2 = g(x2).
The first problem you need to convert this function into parametric form like y2=gy(t), x2=gx(t).
If you will have such parametric representation you can recieve two point sets placed on equal distances on zero-line curve:

```
t=x0:dx:xf;  % same as x above
x2=gx(t);
y2=gy(t);
```

The second problem that you need to receive normal vector for each point of zero-curve.

If you have direct formula y2 = g(x2), you can use equation:

> nx - x2(k) + g'(x2(k))*(ny-y2(k)) = 0
>
> nx^2 + ny^2 = 1

g' denotes derivative of g; x2(k), y2(k) - points of zero-line curve; nx, ny are components of normal vector for each point.

Let you receive two sets nx and ny for each t defined above.

Finally you will have set of required points for force curve:

```
x=x2+nx;
y=y2+ny;
```

Comment: Wow, complicated at the first look but I'll try to make it happen. Thank you for your effort. I'll definitely post a results of my trying :-)